# How to set a json object to the hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store a json object into a hidden input for submit and send to server side.

```
<input type='hidden' id='permissions' name='permissions' />
```

During submission :

```
<input type='hidden' id='permissions' value='[{"1" : "deny", "2": "deny", "5" : "allow"}]' name='permissions' />
```

I used bellow line but not working :

> $('#permissions').val(json_object);

Comment: $('input[name="permissions"]').val(json_obj');

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) like

```
$('#permissions').val(JSON.stringify(json_object));
```

Comment: This error displayed : `Uncaught TypeError: JSON is not a function`

Comment: @BehzadAzizan, open a console, and try `JSON.stringify({'test':12})`, it works

Comment: @AmmerCSE, `JSON.stringify({'test':12})` worked in console, So what's the problem?

Comment: @BehzadAzizan, I dont know. Can you replicate the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: @AmmerCSE I checked my json object and realized that the object not a valid json ! I'm sorry and thanks for you.